# static ip is slowing down my network

Tags: networking, router, static-ip

I  entered settings for my static ip address in my router (TL-WR1043nd) and it worked ok. but then i found out that static ip is causing problems on my network. for example bittorrent sync won't sync with outside-network folders, Plex server streaming is constantly buffering (if i connect to another network), IP TV doesn't work, even tho router can multicast, etc. if I remove the static IP, the problem disappears.

Where's the problem?

Comment: Are you saying you paid for a static public IP address from your ISP, and configured your router to use it on its WAN port, or are you just talking about giving a LAN host a static private IP address, or what?

Comment: I'm talking about WAN port. I keep forgetting about the fact there are two defections of a static IP.

Comment: When you gave it a static IP address, did you give it different DNS addresses to use instead of the ones it had been getting dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I did use the dynamic ones. I also tried using DNS from google (8.8.8.8), but no success, same problem. After that I've tried connecting my computer directly to my ISP innbox v50u device and set a public static IP on that computer. The IP TV did start to work, but plex and bit sync did not. both are installed on on the second computer that is also connected to innbox v50u, to which i'm trying to connect or to sync with. (with no additional settings). The moment I start using dynamic ip, I have no problems with connecting to the other computer on the same main network.